# Check existence of a value in a partition using window function in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having below set of data.

[image]

My goal is to have last column `Exists` with value `YES` when value `C101808491229` exists in the partition `(PARTITION BY COLUMN2)`, else with value `NO`

I was tried to do so in below two ways :

1.`COUNT(CASE WHEN COLUMN5 = 'C101808491229' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN2) AS EXISTS`

2.`CASE WHEN COLUMN5 = 'C101808491229' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS EXISTS`

But neither seemed to work for me.

I hope I made my point clear. Can someone let me know if it is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `MAX` as follows:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN5 = 'C101808491229' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) 
 OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN2) AS EXISTS
```

If `C101808491229` exists then it will return `YES` and max will always give `YES` if there is even one `YES` and other `NO` exists in the partition.

Comment: Accepting this answer for its less complexity.. Thanks it worked smoothly for me

Answer (score 1):

Use this version:

```sql
CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN COLUMN5 = 'C101808491229' THEN 1 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN2) > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS "EXISTS"
```

The inner `CASE` expression does a conditional count per `COLUMN2` partition of how many times `COLUMN5` has the target value.  The outer `CASE` expression displays `YES` when that count be greater than zero, otherwise it displays `NO`.

Note: `EXISTS` is a keyword, please use some other name for your alias.

Comment: This also worked for me... But I have accepted @Popeye answer as it was bit straight forward.. But still upvoted your solution... Thanks for your solution

Comment: @acroniks ... and I agree with your choice, the Popeye solution is very clever.  But note that it relies on the fact that `YES` happens to be greater than `NO`.  The solution I gave would always work regardless of the two string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without window function like following.

```
SELECT YT.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN C.COLUMN2 IS NULL
            THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
        END AS  "EXISTS"
FROM YOURTABLENAME YT
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COLUMN2
    FROM YOURTABLENAME
    WHERE COLUMN5 = 'C101808491229'
    ) C ON YT.COLUMN2 = C.COLUMN2
```